# RegionPlot is producing odd gaps, even for simple functions. Is there an option to prevent this?

Tags: plotting, regions

When I use `RegionPlot` to plot the region between two functions, I get strange gaps in the resulting figure. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

---

For example,

```
RegionPlot[x^2 < y && y < x^4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

produces the following strange result:

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just increase the number of `PlotPoints`

```
RegionPlot[x^2 < y && y < x^4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: As a note, some functions require a lot more than 100 points, I've needed upwards of 500 in some cases. Also, x and y can have different number of points via `PlotPoints -> {100, 150}`.

Comment: This same principle also applies to other `Plot` functions. Sometimes Mathematica gets unlucky with sampling the function and you get discontinuities or odd behavior. In almost every case, either increasing `PlotPoints` or `MaxRecursion` will help.

Answer (score 16):

Or, the `MaxRecursion`:

```
RegionPlot[x^2 < y && y < x^4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, 0, 3},
  MaxRecursion -> 8]
```

The plot commands generally use a adaptive procedure that is applied recursively.  `MaxRecursion` controls how many times this recursion can be applied.  `PlotPoints` by contrast, simply indicates how many points should be used in the initial grid.  It might be simplest to illustrate with the most basic `Plot` command:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, 0, 3},
    Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> 1.1,
    MaxRecursion -> mr, PlotPoints -> pp],
  {mr, 0, 8, 1}, {pp, 4, 100, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a visualization of the sampling mesh for your example function:

```
RegionPlot[{x^2 < y && y < x^4, Not[x^2 < y && y < x^4]}, 
    {x, -3, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, Mesh -> All, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What are the tradeoffs between `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints `?

Comment: MaxRecursion is adaptive and should be the preferable solution (faster for a given required plot accuracy). Compare: ImageDifference[RegionPlot[x^2<y&&y<x^4,{x,-3,3},{y,0,3},MaxRecursion->8],RegionPlot[x^2<y&&y<x^4,{x,-3,3},{y,0,3},PlotPoints->100]]

Comment: @ras See the edit.

Comment: Mark, you have a typo in the first line -> "MaxRecursion".

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius `PlotPoints` is good for making sure features show up; `MaxRecursion` is better for "polishing" off the edges.  (`MaxRecursion` generally can't improve something that isn't there to start with.)

Comment: @AndrewMoylan Isn't it the case the to avoid holes or missing parts, one generally needs to increase PlotPoints, while MaxRecursion is only for increasing the accuracy of *already found* regions?  While in this example it works well, I'm often a bit wary of MaxRecursion because of its exponential nature (increasing it by one may increase the plotting time significantly)

Comment: Yes that's a good point Szabolcs. Brett's comment has the best general advice.

Comment: I edited your answer slightly to include some visualizations I thought were valuable.  Can you please review the changes?