# Problem with plotting a function consisting of HeavisideTheta(s)

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, function-construction, summation

I have the following data

```
data={{1.5, 10}, {25, 26.5}, {29.25, 32.75}, {39.25, 42.5}, {62.5, 67}, {73.5, 80.75}, {87.5, 93}, {102, 104.75}, {111, 114.5}, {123, 129}, {146.5, 152.75}, {161.5, 164.5}, {177, 182.25}, {195.75, 206}, {218.25, 226.25}, {234.75, 237.75}, {246, 252.5}, {258.5, 260.25},{266.25, 272.75}, {280.5, 280.75}, {281.5, 283}, {292,301.25}, {314, 322}, {327.5, 328.5}, {329, 330.25}}
```

Each set of point denotes the starting and ending point of the pulse, so here there are as many pulses as

```
Length[data]
```

I make the function consisting of all these pulses as follows:

```
f[x_] := Sum[HeavisideTheta[x - Part[data, i, 1]] + HeavisideTheta[-x+Part[data,i,2]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]
```

This - as it can be checked - uses 2 Heaviside functions to create each pulse. The problem is while plotting the net pulse function:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, Part[Last[data], 2] + 10}, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

As it can be seen from the "data" list, there are supposed to be the

```
{146.5, 152.75}, {161.5, 164.5} and {280.5, 280.75}, {281.5, 283}
```

**pulses in the plot that are just missing**.

I *just* can't figure out how this is happening. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Adding to `Plot` e.g. these options resolves the problem: `PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 4`.

Comment: Check the documentation of `Plot` carefully or take a look at e.g. [RegionPlot is producing odd gaps, even for simple functions. Is there an option to prevent this?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22/regionplot-is-producing-odd-gaps-even-for-simple-functions-is-there-an-option/39#39). There were many similar questions here, you should search for e.g.  `MaxRecursion`.

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8482/121

Answer (score 3):

Artes's solution is the most general one that works for numerical black box functions as well.

In this special case however, we have a different option: make sure that `Plot` sees the expression of the function.  It will recognize `HeavisideTheta` as a function with a discontinuity, and it will plot the discontinuities as their precise location (not at a numerical approximation of this location, found using Plot's adaptive sampler).

Let's define `f` like this:

```
Clear[f, x]
f[x_] = Sum[HeavisideTheta[x - p[[1]]] + HeavisideTheta[-x + p[[2]]], {p, data}]
```

Make sure to use `=` instead of `:=` to build the complete symbolic function.

Now let's plot as

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, data[[-1, 2]] + 10}, Filling -> Bottom, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic]
```

`ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic` means: use the same line style for the discontinuities as for the rest of the plot.

Notice that this plots *all* the discontinuities, but some of the fillings are missing.  To get those as well, we still need to increase the plot points:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, data[[-1, 2]] + 10}, Filling -> Bottom, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

But at least it is *guaranteed* that *all* the discontinuities will be found without needing to use a high `PlotPoints` and any `MaxRecursion` settings.  The manual `PlotPoints` setting is only to make sure that the fillings are all present as well.

Reference: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exclusions.html

Answer (score 1):

As *Artes* noted, adding to Plot e.g. these options resolves the problem:

```
PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 4
```